# Python 3: How do I import __init__.py from a module in its package?

Tags: python

I'm on Python 3.7. I created a *foo* module, which has the following folder layout:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
```

I put all the code for the foo package in the *__init__.py* file. I'm able to run `import foo` from other scripts as normal.

Later on, I wanted to add a *util.py* file to this package. The folder layout became:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    util.py
```

My question is: Inside *util.py*, I'd like to access the classes, functions, etc. defined in *__init__.py*. How can I "import" *__init__.py* from the *util.py* file? Is this even possible? If I have to rearrange my code, then how?

I've tried to add the following to *util.py*:

```
from . import __init__
print(__init__.some_var_in_init)
```

But I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "util.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(__init__.some_var_in_init)
AttributeError: 'method-wrapper' object has no attribute 'some_var_in_init'
```

So I'm guessing that's not the way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

`import foo` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It isn't enough to add `import foo`, but the parent folder must be added as well:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

import foo
print(foo.some_var_in_init)
```